# ng-model using blank selected row (not using defined selected placeholder)

Tags: angularjs

This works:

```
<select class="secureProfile">
    <option class="placeholder" selected disabled>välj ett alternativ...</option>
    <option value="male">Man</option>
    <option value="female">Kvinna</option>
</select>
```

This does not:

```
<select data-ng-model="gender" class="secureProfile">
    <option class="placeholder" selected disabled>välj ett alternativ...</option>
    <option value="male">Man</option>
    <option value="female">Kvinna</option>
</select>
```

For some reason when applying `data-ng-model` it seems to get rid of the placeholders, looks like this (picture displays the error):

[image]

Controller:

```
.controller('secureProfile', ['$document', '$compile', '$scope', '$window', '$location', '$http', '$cookies', 'socket', 'textAngularManager', 'bridge', function ($document, $compile, $scope, $window, $location, $http, $cookies, socket, textAngularManager, bridge) {
    $scope.gender = null;
}])
```

When I load the page for a blink second it displays it correctly but then decides to make a blank selected row. Any ideas?

Comment: can you post a fiddle? the image that you show is the desired result or the wrong result

Comment: @gaurav5430 The image displays the wrong result!

Comment: What do you give to ng-model gender  ?

Comment: You must set this gender at first then it will have the default selected value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as you added `data-ng-model`, your select element shows value assigned to `gender`, which is probably undefined when application starts. If you want to show "välj ett alternativ..." as selected option, you have to add this in controller:

```
$scope.gender = "välj ett alternativ...";
```

Comment: Thanks. I noticed that I *have* to have `välj ett alternativ...` as an option for this to work. So both angularjs code and html code is needed.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set value property

HTML

```
<select data-ng-model="gender" class="secureProfile">
  <option class="placeholder" value="" selected disabled>välj ett alternativ...</option>
  <option value="male">Man</option>
  <option value="female">Kvinna</option>
</select>
```

<kbd>**[`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/6o4s2wfr/)**</kbd>

Comment: Ok tried it, doesn't seem to work, I've updated my question with controller code.

Comment: you didn't provide value field  `<option class="placeholder" value="" selected disabled>`

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi why would OP need `$scope.gender = null;` to specify there ?

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi I was wanting `välj ett alternativ...` to be displayed :) Not value ""

Comment: If he don't set null then he have to provide text property as default as there is no value property for default value. It would break the flow like i am choosing value property for other and setting text property for default value. @PankajParkar bro

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi sir it will still work without setting `gender` value as it would be considered as `undefined` select will show default place holder https://jsfiddle.net/ttayv25f/1/

Comment: @PankajParkar bro thanks for the fiddle . I got your point :)

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi also you don't need to have `value="" selected disabled` attributes on your placeholder..that doesn't make sense

Comment: why ? can you explain ? @PankajParkar

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi that was my bad `value=""` should be there to understand it that whenever `gender` will not have value to show placeholder option.